# 'RCTVersion.h' file not found

Tags: xcode, react-native, react-native-ios

I'm facing this issue 'RCTVersion.h' file not found. I started getting this error after by mistakenly linking manually while I have a pod file. Before doing this, it was building successfully.

What I've tried so far:
cd ios/
rm -rf Podfile.lock
rm -rf Pods/
pod install --repo-update

Clean, Rebuild, close and open again - did couple of times
still no luck

React and Firebase versions:

"react": "16.0.0-beta.5",

"react-native": "0.49.3",

"@react-native-firebase/app": "^7.3.1",

"@react-native-firebase/crashlytics": "^7.1.7",

[image: 'RCTVersion.h'_file_not_found_error]

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'SomeApp' do
  # Comment the next line if you don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  #use_frameworks!

  # Pods for SomeApp

# add the Firebase pod for Google Analytics
pod 'Firebase/Analytics'
# add pods for any other desired Firebase products
# https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/setup#available-pods
pod 'Firebase/Crashlytics'

  target 'SomeAppTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

end

target 'SomeApp-tvOS' do
  # Comment the next line if you don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  #use_frameworks!

  # Pods for SomeApp-tvOS

  target 'SomeApp-tvOSTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

end
```

I'm new to this, any help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!